# Why is the implementation of the map function of Collection inconsistent with the actual

Tags: swift

I recently read the Swift source code and saw that the `map` function of Collection is implemented as follows

```swift
   @inlinable
   public func map<T>(
     _ transform: (Element) throws -> T
   ) rethrows -> [T] {
     // TODO: swift-3-indexing-model - review the following
     let n = self.count
     if n == 0 {
       return []
     }

     var result = ContiguousArray<T>()
     result. reserveCapacity(n)

     var i = self. startIndex

     for _ in 0..<n {
       result.append(try transform(self[i]))
       formIndex(after: &i)
     }

     _expectEnd(of: self, is: i)
     return Array(result)
   }
```

It seems that the `map` function will visit the i subscript elements in turn according to its own size, and call the transform closure parameter one by one.

I wrote the following code to verify, and found that it is different from the Collection source code implementation

```swift
var array = [0, 1, 2]

array.map { index -> Void in
     array[2] = -1
     print("\(index)")
}
```

According to the Collection source code, the print result of this code should be

```
0
1
-1
```

but actually it prints

```
0
1
2
```

I'm wondering why this code behaves inconsistently with the source code.

---

Update：

It looks like there is some misunderstanding in my example code. Actually I know the correct usage of `map`, I just want to verify my understanding of the source code.

So for the sake of accuracy, I decided to modify my example code a bit

```swift
var array = [0, 1, 2]

let newArray = array. map { element -> Int in
      array[element] = -1
      return element
}

print(array)
print(newArray)
```

Now this code uses `map` correctly, and I modify the content of array in map, and return `element` to form `newArray`, the printed result is as follows

```
[-1, -1, -1]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Which version of Swift is that source code from? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L673) for the implementation of `map`, and it's different from what you showed.

Comment: Try to print edited array element not the index (means original array element)

Comment: In fact, my source code also comes from Github. What I look at is the implementation of Collection, not Sequence. I also looked at the implementation of Sequence. Except for the use of iterator, it is roughly the same as Collection.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1192

Answer (score 2):

Let me rewrite this in a simpler way that I believe will be uncontroversial, and then hopefully it will be clear that your code is equivalent:

```
// A free function that accepts an array and a transform
func iterate(over: [Int], _ transform: (Int) -> Void) {
    let n = over.count
    var i = over.startIndex
    for _ in 0..<n {
        transform(over[i])
        over.formIndex(after: &i)
    }
}

var array = [0, 1, 2]
iterate(over: array) { value in
    array[2] = -1
    print(value)
}
print(array)
```

This will print the same as your example:

```
0
1
2
[0, 1, -1]
```

This is exactly as should be expected in Swift. `over` is a copy of `array`, so `array[2] = -1` has nothing to do with `over`. Value-type parameters **always** are copies (even `inout` are copies; they just get copied back at the end). The behavior hopefully is clear from that.

The only difference between this and your example is that it is called as a function rather than a method, but that is no difference at all. `over` and `self` play precisely the same roles in this code and behave exactly the same way. `self` is a copy. To demonstrate, this is a mechanical conversion of the function taking `Array` to an extension on `Array`:

```
extension Array<Int> {
    func iterate(_ transform: (Int) -> Void) {
        let n = self.count
        var i = self.startIndex
        for _ in 0..<n {
            transform(self[i])
            self.formIndex(after: &i)
        }
    }
}

var array = [0, 1, 2]
array.iterate { value in
    array[2] = -1
    print(value)
}
print(array)
```

It behaves identically (as should be expected). Changing the parameter's name from `over` to `self` does not change the behavior. `map` is the same. It's equivalent to this (inlining the method):

```
var array = [0, 1, 2]

let `self` = array  // This makes a copy; `let` because it's non-mutating
let n = `self`.count
var i = `self`.startIndex
for _ in 0..<n {
    array[2] = -1
    print(`self`[i])
    `self`.formIndex(after: &i)
}

print(array)
```

For more on this, see [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/classesandstructures/#Structures-and-Enumerations-Are-Value-Types) in The Swift Programming Language:

> In fact, all of the basic types in Swift — integers, floating-point numbers, Booleans, strings, arrays and dictionaries — are value types, and are implemented as structures behind the scenes.
>
> All structures and enumerations are value types in Swift. This means that any structure and enumeration instances you create — and any value types they have as properties — are always copied when they’re passed around in your code.

Comment: "`self` is a copy." Woah, I didn't realize this. (Even though I knew mutating methods are essentially `self: inout Self`, and so forth). Interesting!

Comment: Wonderful! This is a little difficult for me, but very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually using the `map` function correctly in your example, so it's unclear what you're trying to test. But if you append a further statement `print(array)` you will see that the original `array` was indeed changed.

```
    var array = [0, 1, 2]

    array.map { index -> Void in
        array[2] = -1
        print("\(index)")
    }
    print(array) // [0, 1, -1]
```

Your call to `array[2] = -1` does not affect the array that we are looping over (and from which you are getting your poorly named `index`), because it is a *copy* of the original `array`.

Comment: Yes! I also think that there is a copy of the array, but the problem is that this behavior has not been confirmed in the source code. Is there something wrong with the source code I read?

Answer (score 0):

You get an *inconsistent* result because actually you don't use the `map` functionality at all.

The signature of `map`

```
func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

means the following:

- It does **not** modify the array in place, it returns a new array with the transformed elements.
- In the closure `(Element) throws -> T` you get each element – which is an immutable copy of the element by the way – and you have to return the modified/transformed value.

`index -> Void` is pointless because you don't return anything in the closure, instead you modify the array in place, in practice you overwrite the 3rd element of the array with -1 three times. Further `index` is not the index, it's the element. If the array is `[2, 4, 6]` then `index` is `2, 4, 6` not `0, 1, 2`.

If you want to set the element with value 2 to -1 using `map` you have to write

```
let result = array.map { element -> Int in
    if element == 2 {
        return -1
    } else {
        return element
    }
}
```

`result` will be `[0, 1, -1]`, on the other hand `array` remains unchanged.

But the **real** purpose of `map` is a transformation like

```
let result = array.map { element -> String in
    return "\(element * 2) times"
}
```

Now `result` is `["0 times", "2 times", "4 times"]`

The magic of generics is that you don't even need to specify the return type, this is sufficient

```
let result = array.map { "\($0 * 2) times" }
```